# Trouble getting started with Eclipse CDT & mingw

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Howdie all,

I've installed Eclipse CDT and MinGW with GCC.

Added the mingw\bin to my path environment variable.

When attempting to create a new C++ project with the HelloWorld wizard, I get a build error:

```
make: **** [app.o] Error 127

Error launching external scanner info generator (gcc -E -P -v -dD ...
```

EDIT:

OK the make problem is solved, does anyone know how to fix this other warning about the external scanner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AH HA!

in the C/C++ Build settings, make sure the build command is:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile
```

Thanks me!